# Create new table that only displays previous six months of data from original table [Excel]

Tags: excel, sorting, subset

I currently have a table in Excel that is structured like this:

[image: Full dataset]

I would like to have another sheet in my Excel workbook that only displays data from the last 6 months like this:

[image: Last 6 months of full dataset]

Is there a simple way to do this?

If my data was nicely structured, I might would be able to use the `offset` function as mentioned in [this article](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/offset.html), but I feel like there should be a simpler way to accomplish this.

Comment: Just use a filter

Comment: @RonRosenfeld How do I create an entirely new sheet with the same data table so that the sheet with 6 months of data changes dynamically as the main data table changes?

Comment: If you want the new table to change dynamically, you'll need either use formulas, or construct a connection (using `Power Query` aka `Get&Transform`) with an event trigger.  Since the table will be on a different sheet, you could use an `Activate` event to trigger the data query.

Comment: A pivot table won't work?